# Nissan Leaf 2013 - 2015 Model

Tags: nissan, electric-vehicle

I like the **Nissan Leaf**.

I want to know if it can travel a maximum **180** Kms. Is there a portable device that could charge the vehicle?

Why do car experts say it is not good to charge it daily from a **Rapid Charging** Station?

Could the brake pads last **90K** miles ?

Does the **Nissan Leaf** with solar panel charge the vehicle rapidly or not?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I changed your question to remove the shopping advice so your question would not be closed.  I focused the question around the technical components of the Nissan Leaf.  I see you are asking multiple questions.  Thank you for you contribution to this SE site.  Let's see if the question stays open.  Good luck.  Cheers!

Comment: I don't know anything specific about the Leaf, but the brake pads almost certainly won't last 90K miles and solar panels provide a tiny amount of energy compared to that of moving a car.

Comment: I don't see that the Nissan Leaf has solar panels.  Am I confused here?

Comment: as zach stated in his comment.  Brake pads will not last 90K miles.  No way.  Not a reasonable ask.   :-)   Loosely agreed upon belief for the life of a brake pad is 30K to 70K depending on the type of driving.  City/Hwy, etc....

Comment: There is an addon device thats marketed as an aftermarket range extender that consists of some lithium cells and some control electronics .

Comment: Can you describe the solar panels electrical properties ?

Comment: @DucatiKiller, Depending on commute and and driving habits, brake pads on hybrids and EVs can reportedly last well over 90K miles. DarthPuppy claims that [a Highlander Hybrid had over 140k+ on the original pads](https://mynissanleaf.com/viewtopic.php?t=24948).

Answer (score 1):

A portable recharging device would be a generator. Rapid charging will raise battery temperature. It's deemed to be OK to do it sometimes, but not all the time. Remember that the batteries age naturally just like we do. I suppose it's like drinking and/or smoking - you can't do it all the time. Everything in moderation.

It's been theorized that brake pads will last a very long time because of the regenerative braking system doing about 80% of the work. The solar panel on My 2011 Leaf is configured to recharge the accessory battery only. I like my Leaf and run high Kms. The jury is still out on how long the expensive lithium packs will last before replacement is necessary.Some people are saying that the capacity of the battery will slowly degrade which will make the vehicle useless at some application dependent point.